# Confusion when using the self keyword

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a few questions about this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.myArray= @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"];
}
```

I know the self keyword means that's method will be sent to the receiver of that message, and I know when and how to use it if i was creating a simple command utility code, but when learning about creating an iPhone app and using the storyboard every time I see the self keyword it confuses me, I don't know which object is the receiver 
**2nd question**, I know that `@[@"object", @"object"];`is quick way to create an `NSArray` object, but "myArray" is a property not an `NSArray` object. please explain, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArray` is. The name of a property, as you say. By default, the compiler will create an instance variable called `_myArray` that's used by that property. In any case, because you've declared the property to be of type `NSArray *` (and not readonly) you can assign an array to it.

The `self` keyword is simply a pointer to the "current" object, some instance of the class that you're writing code for when you type "self". If you assign something to `self.myArray`, the class in which you make that assignment needs to have a `myArray` property. In your code example, `self` is a pointer to the particular instance of `ViewController` that just loaded its view. None of that changes when you're writing an iPhone apportion using a storyboard. `self` is *always* the object receiving the method in which `self` is used. (Note: when used in a class method, i.e. one that starts with `+`, the object receiving the method is the class itself, not an instance of the class. Don't worry about this if it sounds confusing -- it doesn't come up all that often.)

If you find an expression like `self.myArray` confusing, it may help to know that property syntax is just shorthand for a method call. Also, `self` in an expression like that isn't special at all. The syntax is `foo.bar` where `foo` can any object pointer (including `self`) and `bar` can be any property of the object pointed to by `foo`. The expression translates directly to either `[foo bar]` or `[foo setBar:...]`, depending on whether you're reading or assigning a value to the property. So,

```
self.myArray = @[a, b, c];
```

means *exactly* the same as:

```
[self setMyArray:@[a, b, c]];
```

Comment: I think I got what I was missing from the "self keyword" concept from your answers, but still creating an NSArray object from a property is a mystery to me... please explain more about this sentence "In any case, because you've declared the property to be of type NSArray * (and not readonly) you can assign an array to it."

Comment: In your example, you're not creating the array *from* a property. You're creating an array, and then assigning a pointer to the array *to* a property. A property is *really* just a pair of methods that get and set an instance variable, but since most getters and setters work the same way the compiler will generate them for you. Your `self.myArray = someArray` is the same as `[self setMyArray:someArray]`, and the `-setMyArray:` method (along with an instance variable `_myArray`) is generated for you. There's a more complete explanation in Apple's docs: http://bit.ly/R8USc3

Comment: in this code: `NSDate *selected = [self.datePicker date];` self is an instance of the viewController that controls the datepicker in the storyboard?

Comment: @IsaacMajdi It's impossible to say what `self` is in that example without more context. Does that line appear in the class definition (the .m file) for a view controller that manages a date picker? If yes, then yes, `self` is an instance of that view controller class. `self` will only ever appear in the `@implementation` of a class, so if you're not sure what type `self` refers to, scroll up and find the line that starts with the `@implementation` directive. `self` is either that class itself (in the `+` class methods) or an instance of that class (in the `-` instance methods).

Answer (score 1):

`self` always corresponds to the self class. So every instance of a class will have its own self.

In your case `myArray` is a property of Class ViewController. Here you can refer to the property by using `self.myArray` or `_myArray`.

In the following statement you are creating an array with four strings and adding it to `myArray`.

```
self.myArray= @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"];
```

---

Your wordings in the question :

> I know the self keyword means thats method will be sent to the
>   receiver of that message

is valid for a method call where you use it as :

```
[self aMethod];
```

Even in this you are calling a method which is a part of the class. If you call any method which is not of the current(self) class then you call it by using that class' object name as:

```
SomeClass *someClassObject = ...
[someClassObject itsMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

"self" is a pointer to object to which the method belongs. In your case you may have many instances of `ViewController` and each of them can call `viewDidLoad` and in that method "self" is the pointer to the instance itself. To look at it from the C perspective you could create a method using pointer to function where you would also send own pointer to the function called "self", for instance void `foo(MyClass *self);` to call it then `myClassInstance->foo(myClassInstance);` this procedure kind of simulates methods but you always need to send instance pointer as well (self). So there should be no confusion as to what "self" is except it is more commonly known by "this" keyword. It is just a reference to the object on which the method is being called.

The property is just a convenience of usually 2 methods called getter and setter. When creating a property `@property NSArray *myArray` you will actually generate a pointer  usually `NSArray *_myArray;` then a getter:

```
 - (NSArray *)myArray {
    return _myArray;
 }
```

And a setter

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSArray *)myArray {
    _myArray = myArray;    
 }
```

How getters and setters are created depends on property attributes (strong, weak, readonly...). You may even override any of these methods or both. So as you stated "but "myArray" is a property not an NSArray object" a property can have truly any type.